# removeFromSuperLayer occasionally not working for sub UIView on UICollectionViewCell iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For an iOS app in Swift, I add a gradient layer to a UIView in a custom UICollectionViewCell Subclass with an extension method.

```
   extension UIView {

       func addGradientLayer() {
           let color1 = Constants.Colors.gradientStart
           let color2 = Constants.Colors.gradientEnd
           let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
           gradientLayer.name = Constants.gradientLayerName
           gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
           gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
           self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
       }
   }
```

I have two states for my UICollectionViewCell Subclass, either with a gradient layer or without.

```
    if true { // bool statement

        cell.listeningView.addGradientLayer()

    } else {

        if let layers = cell.listeningView.layer.sublayers {

            for (index, layer) in layers.enumerated() {

                if layer.name == Constants.gradientLayerName {

                    cell.listeningView.layer.sublayers?[index].removeFromSuperlayer()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        cell.listeningView.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.newsFeedItemNotInFocus
    }
```

Occasionally when my cells are dequeuing the gradientLayer is unable to be removed, despite the removeFromSuperLayer method being called. Does anyone know why this is happening? and how I can ensure the layer gets removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason would be that you are adding this sublayer more than once. Try to remove the break inside the loop and test it again.

**Fast solution:** remove the layer before adding it again.

```
if let layers = cell.listeningView.layer.sublayers {

    for (index, layer) in layers.enumerated() {

        if layer.name == Constants.gradientLayerName {

            cell.listeningView.layer.sublayers?[index].removeFromSuperlayer()
            //break with or without
        }
    }
}
cell.listeningView.addGradientLayer()
```

Comment: Thanks @hasan83 - yep I was clearly adding layer upon layer and then only removing one

Answer (score 0):

There is at least second reason for remove..() not working: if the code is executed not in the main thread. Then the call succeeds but there is no effect.

Comment: he is doing that for the cell therefore I don't see how can be in background thread. it will be in collection view delegate methods.